# Обмен местами строк матрицы

Tags: c++, матрицы

Необходимо поменять местами две строки матрицы. Нашел в интернете несколько примеров в которых используется поэлементный обмен. Мне такой код не очень нравится, поэтому я написал свой вариант обмена строк матрицы с использованием ссылочных переменных и указателей, но вот беда - я сам не до конца понимаю как он работает ( он работает, проверял на произвольных матрицах ).

Объясните, пожалуйста.

(В данном конкретном случае меняю местами строки в зависимости от четности индекса)

```
template <typename T>
void swapRows(T **matrix, int rowsQuantity) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < rowsQuantity - 1; i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
            T &temp = *matrix[i];
            matrix[i] = matrix[i+1];
            matrix[i+1] = &temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Практическим путем выяснил что " *matrix[i] " возвращает значение первого элемента i-ой строки. Честно говоря, не понятно почему так. Знаю, что имя массива это указатель на его первый элемент, видимо, это как-то связано, но точную логическую цепочку не получается провести.

Ссылочная переменная " temp " получает адрес этого первого элемента i-ой строки.

Как работает " matrix[i+1] = &temp; " не очень понятно.

Comment: Зачем вы писали это `T &temp = *matrix[i];` - совершенно не понятно. Это лишь запутывает код. Можно было просто написать `T *temp = matrix[i]; matrix[i] = matrix[i+1]; matrix[i+1] = temp;`. А у вас получился просто кусок кода с "четным количеством несуразностей", в результате чего они компенсируют друг друга.

Comment: Да, я уже после сделал так, как вы написали. Буду использовать именно такую версию, но все равно интересно получить объяснение на то, как работает код с ссылочными переменными.

Си изучаю недавно, поэтому некоторые нюансы работы с ссылками\указателями не понятны.

Comment: @toopeachok, судя по тому, что функция является шаблонной, это `C++`, но не `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указатель `matrix`  содержит адрес указателья(является указателем на указатель).   `matrix[i]` это указатель `(matrix + i)`,  `*matrix[i]` это первый элемент в массиве(строке) `matrix + i`.

```
T &temp = *matrix[i];
```

означает, что первому элементу `i - той`  строки  придаем имя `temp`

```
matrix[i] = matrix[i+1];
```

теперь `matrix[i]` указывает на начало того же массива, что и `matrix[i + 1]`

`matrix[i+1] = &temp;` 
теперь `i + 1` - тый указатель получает значение:  адрес первого  элемента `i` - той строки, равно, указывает на строку `i`

Практически вы могли бы написать функцию проще:

```
template <typename T>
void swapRows(T **matrix, int rowsQuantity) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < rowsQuantity - 1; i += 2) 
      std::iter_swap(matrix[i], matrix[i + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Необходимо поменять местами две строки матрицы.

Во-первых, надо определиться, каким образом объявляется матрица.

Самый простой подход - это объявить матрицу в виде двумерного массива. Например,

```
const size_t N = 3;
int a[N][N] = 
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 },
    { 7, 8, 9 }
};
```

В этом случае приведенная вами функция не годится, то есть не будет работать, так как она принимает указатель на указатель в качестве аргумента, а не двумерный массив.

Для вашей функции матрица определяется скорей всего динамически (хотя в частном случае это может быть и локальный массив) как указатель на динамически выделенный одномерный массив, элементы которого в свою очередь являются указателями на динамически выделенные одномерные массивы.

Например,

```
const size_t N = 3;

int **a = new int *[N];

int value = 1;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    a[i] = new int[N] { value++, value++, value++ };
}
```

Теперь указатель `a` можно передать в вашу функцию в качестве первого аргумента.

Внутри этой функции обмениваются соседние элементы динамически созданного массива `a`, которые являются указателями на первые элементы других выделенных динамически массивов, как

```
int **a = new int *[N];
```

следующим образом

```
for ( int i = 0; i < rowsQuantity - 1; i++) {
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
        T &temp = *matrix[i];
        matrix[i] = matrix[i+1];
        matrix[i+1] = &temp;
    }
}
```

Здесь выражение `matrix[i]` дает значение элемента, то есть значение указателя, в `i-ом` элементе массива `matrix`. Этот указатель содержит адрес первого элемента `i-го` динамически выделенного массива.

Объявление

```
T &temp = *matrix[i];
```

объявляет ссылку на этот первый элемент `i-го`.  Поэтому если взять адрес этого первого элемента, используя ссылку

```
matrix[i+1] = &temp;
```

то значение выражения `&item` будет равно значению, хранящемся в выражении  `matrix[i]`.

Эквивалентный код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
    T *temp = matrix[i];
    matrix[i] = matrix[i+1];
    matrix[i+1] = temp;
}
```

Имейте в виду, что есть стандартная функция `std::swap`, объявленная в заголовке `<utility>`. которая выполняет данную операцию. С помощью этой функции вы могли бы просто написать

```
if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
    std::swap( matrix[i], matrix[i+1] );
}
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа, которая использует два подхода к определению матрицы: первый - в виде массива и второй - в виде набора динамических массивов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, size_t N>
void swapRows( T ( &a )[N][N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i + 1 < N; i += 2 )
    {
        std::swap( a[i], a[i + 1] );
    }
}

template <typename T>
void swapRows( T **a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i + 1 < n; i += 2 )
    {
        std::swap( a[i], a[i + 1] );
    }
}

int main() 
{
{
    const size_t N = 3;

    int **a = new int *[N];

    int value = 1;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = new int[N] { value++, value++, value++ };
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout <<  a[i][j] << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    swapRows( a, N );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            std::cout <<  a[i][j] << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

}

{
    const size_t N = 3;
    int a[N][N] = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    swapRows( a );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

4 5 6 
1 2 3 
7 8 9 

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

4 5 6 
1 2 3 
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

В представленном коде происходит следующее:

1)

```
template <typename T>
void swapRows(T **matrix, int rowsQuantity) {
```

Эта шаблонная функция первым аргументом принимает указатель на указатель на какой-то тип. Судя по всему, предполагается, что этот тип является элементарным. Например, `int`, `float`, `double`.

Исходя из того, что `matrix` - это указатель на указатель, ваша матрица представлена как массив, в котором хранятся указатели на массивы (строки), в которых хранятся сами элементы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где `matrix` - это указатель, в котором хранится адрес массива `ABC`;

2)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsQuantity - 1; i++) {
```

Происходит обход всей матрицы по строкам. Здесь сразу видны две проблемы:

1. Нет контроля значения переменной `rowsQuantity`;
2. Переменная типа `int` не вполне подходит для адресации элементов массива. Переменная типа `size_t` подойдет гораздо лучше.

3)

```
if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
```

Действия выполняются при `посещении` каждой строки, чей индекс кратен двум (0, 2, 4, и пр.). И действия, соответственно, выполняются попарно над строками 0-1, 2-3, 4-5.Это не совсем рационально, потому что такой подход выполняет в два раза больше инкрементов переменной `i`, в два раза больше делений с остатком и в два раза больше сравнений, чем реально необходимо.

Гораздо рациональнее было бы выполнять `i += 2`, вообще отбросив деление с остатком и проверку. Но такой подход потребует выполнение проверки целочисленного переполнения переменной `i`.

4)

```
T &temp = *matrix[i];
matrix[i] = matrix[i+1];
matrix[i+1] = &temp;
```

На первый взгляд, это довольно идиоматическая запись, необходимая для классического обмена местами двух значений с использованием промежуточной переменной:

```
temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

Но не совсем. Я не уверен до конца, что происходит в недрах компилятора, и что по этому поводу говорит `Стандарт`.

`matrix[i]` - получает значение указателя на строку матрицы (адрес массива со значениями строки). `*` - разыменовывает данный адрес, получая значение (значения) всей строки. По всей видимости, значение строки помещается в ссылочную переменную `temp`.

Я не специалист по `C++`, но мне данный код кажется очень странным. По логике, ссылка является сущностью времени компиляции, иначе говоря - это просто всевдоним для чего-то. То есть, эти три странные строчки можно свести к двум:

```
x = y;
y = x;
```

В результате чего и в `x`, и в `y` будет находится изначальное значение `y`. Но, по-видимому, компилятор в принципе понимает, что вы от него хотите. А может быть, это неопределенное поведение. Точно сказать не могу, потому что текущий стандарт `C++` занимает почти 2000 страниц.

5)

```
matrix[i+1] = &temp;
```

Здесь происходит использование адреса данных, связанных со ссылкой `temp`.

PS. Я бы рекомендовал как можно реже и меньше смешивать `C++` с его `C` подмножеством. Не потому, что `C` плохо, а потому что такое смешивание имеет ряд существенных минусов.

Во-первых, низкоуровневая явность `C` несовместима с высокоуровневой неявностью `C++`. Это гарантированно будет приводить к трудным для понимания ошибкам даже во вполне тривиальном коде. Так же это будет вынуждать вас писать еще больше кода, чем при использовании одного только `C` - вот такой парадокс.

Во-вторых, смешивание ссылок с указателями, шаблонов с макросами и исключений с кодами возврата приводит к неподдающимся анализу ситуациям, потому что названные элементы противоречивы в деталях, хотя поверхностно кажутся очень похожими.

Comment: В той части, где вы сами плохо знаете(преставляете), лучше не пытаться обьяснять...

Answer (score 0):

`matrix` имеет тип указатель на указатель на `T`, что можно также трактовать как массив указателей на `T`. Аргумент `rowQuantity`, по всей видимости, содержит количество элементов этого массива. Немного дополню ващ код:

```
T &temp = *(matrix[i]);    
matrix[i] = matrix[i + 1];
matrix[i + 1] = &temp;
```

`matrix[i]` возвращает итый элемент массива указателей на `T`, далее `*(итый указатель)` разыменовывает итый указатель и возвращает ссылку на первый элемент итой строки, полученная ссылка получает имя `temp`. `matrix[i] = matrix[i + 1]` итому элементу присваивается итый плюс один элемент, теперь в них содержатся одинаковые указатели. `matrix[i + 1] = &temp`, здесь `&temp` возвращает указатель на то на что ссылается `temp`, а именно на первый элемент итой строки, полученный адрес помещается в итый плюс один элемент массива.

Вот эквивалентный и более понятный код:

```
T * temp = matrix[i];
matrix[i] = matrix[i + 1];
matrix[i + 1] = temp;
```