# С++ ссылка на временный объект

Tags: c++, объекты, ссылки

Хочу разобраться в двух следующих вопросах:

1) До какого момента ссылка на временный объект остается валидна? Иначе говоря, когда временный объект уничтожается?

```
void func_1(const object &_obj)
{
    // Долгая и сложная работа с _obj.
}

int main()
{
    func_1(object(...));
}
```

2) Видел код, подобный этому:

```
object a, b;
// ...
object &temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;

// Код работал, обменивая значения местами, хотя я всегда думал, 
// что ссылка - это просто синоним, и данный код должен был привести
// к тому, что в `a` и `b` окажется изначальное значение `b`.
```

Comment: `func_1(object &_obj)` `func_1(object(...));` - это даже компилироваться не должно, нельзя создать ссылку на временный объект, только константную ссылку - типа `func_1(const object& _obj)`

Comment: И то что написано во втором случае тоже не будет обменивать значения местами

Comment: `const` просто потерял, поправил.

Comment: Ок, тогда для первого ссылка внутри функции будет валидна всегда - ведь она константная и чтобы её создать её нужно чем-то проинициализровать. То есть в main при вызове функции будет создан временный объект `object`, ссылка на него передана внутрь функции, функция отработает, объект разрушится. Но это я своими словами, щас эксперты правильными словами всё объяснят =)

Сделайте простой класс со всеми конструкторами и деструктором, внутри которых пишите в std::cout сообщения, и посмотрите как это работает.

Comment: Я не могу понять, как работает вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931800/Обмен-местами-строк-матрицы

Comment: Там же ответ есть. Крайне подробный.

Comment: но тот код кардинально отличается от вашего. там же martix это **, т.е. указатель на массив указателей. И обмениваются местами только указатели в массиве, сами объекты как были так и остаются на своих местах в памяти

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) До какого момента ссылка на временный объект остается валидна?
>   Иначе говоря, когда временный объект уничтожается?
>
> ```
> void func_1(const object &_obj)
> {
>     // Долгая и сложная работа с _obj.
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     func_1(object(...));
> }
> ```

Здесь временный объект уничтожается, грубо говоря, когда завершается выполнение строки кода, в которой он был создан.

Не "настоящей" строки, а "логической" - которая заканчивается символом `;`, а не символом переноса строки.

> 2) Видел код, подобный этому:
>
> ```
> object a, b;
> // ...
> object &temp = a;
> a = b;
> b = temp;
>
> // Код работал, обменивая значения местами, хотя я всегда думал, 
> // что ссылка - это просто синоним, и данный код должен был привести
> // к тому, что в `a` и `b` окажется изначальное значение `b`.
> ```

Это не может работать.

В [оригинальном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931800) ситуация совсем другая. Там ссылку используют, чтобы поменять местами два указателя. Примерно так:

```
int *a = ...;
int *b = ...;

// ...

int &t = *b;
b = a;
a = &t;
```

По сути, это классический swap с использованием третьей переменной. Можно переписать его с использованием указателя вместо ссылки, смысл не изменится:

```
int *a = ...;
int *b = ...;

// ...

int *t = b;
b = a;
a = t;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я просто не мог понять, что происходит в том примере, уже начал сомневаться в том, что ссылка, это лишь синоним для обращения к объекту.

Comment: Мне кажется все варианты не правильны. Думаю, вы хотели:  int *t = b; b = a;
a = t;

Comment: То есть, запись вида `int &t = *a` создает ссылку, которая связана с объектом, на который указывает указатель `a`?

Comment: и константная ссылька  продливает жизнь временного обьекта  до конца программы(функции)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan простите что ? `int main(){   {const int& a = 5; std::cout << a << std::endl;} много другого кода    return 0 ;}`

Comment: @vegorov, и что вы хотели сказать? Что так нельзя?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan хотя нет, вы правы, но только с оговоркой. Не до конца программы(функции), а до конца области видимости. scope или как там это называется

Comment: @vegorov, ну так и называется,  все верно. Но все обьекты стека живут до конца  scope. Поэтому как лучше обьяснять, я не могу формулировать, но как бы константная ссылька  продливает жизнь временного обьекта на столько, сколько живет локальный(не временный) обьект. Я это хотел сказать

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *"Мне кажется все варианты не правильны."* Да, точно. Исправил.

Comment: *"и константная ссылька продливает жизнь временного обьекта"* Насколько я понимаю, тут продления не происходит, потому что объект сам по себе существует дольше, чем выполняется функция.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  по поводу ссыльки, это не замечание вам, а  желание дополнить сказанное

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример для наглядности. Запустите и посмотрите.

```
#include <iostream>





int main()
{
    int** arr = new int*[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        arr[i] = new int[10];
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            arr[i][j] = i* 10 + j;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;
    int& ref = *arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = &ref;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    delete []arr;

    int a = 1, b = 2;
    int& temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a:" << a << " b:" << b << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Больше вам спасибо за помощь.